# Angular library `outside of the configured 'rootDir'` error when sharing dependencies

Tags: angular, shared-libraries

I keep reading that you can use modules, components and interfaces within an Angular library. But I'm consistently getting an `outside of the configured 'rootDir'` error.

```
projects
  - app
  - lib
    - common-entry-pt
      - src
        - dumb.component-one.ts
        - dumb.component-two.ts
        - dumb.module.ts
        - ng-package.json
        - public-api.ts
    - entry-pt-one
      - src
        - entry-pt-one.component.ts 
        - entry-pt-one.module.ts <— importing dumb.module.ts gives “file outside of the configured ‘rootDir'"
        - entry-pt-one.service.ts
        - ng-package.json
        - public-api.ts
```

The code differs depending on import path or attempt.

```
error NG3004: Unable to import class ToolsModule.
dumb.module.ts is outside of the configured 'rootDir'.
```

Does anyone have an example of sharing deps within the library?

UPDATE:
I started from scratch and used strictly used the cli to recreate each file/folder. Nothing different at all and it worked.

Comment: What’s the problem / error

Comment: Can you show the actual import statements please? Could it be that you reference it with relative paths instead of an absolute path from paths-mapping for the library?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path alias to the `tsconfig.json` of the `entry-pt-one` library.

```
"paths": {
  "dumb-components-library": ["lib/src/common-entry-pt/public-api.ts"],
}
```

then in the modules of `entry-pt-one` you can do import using the alias:

```
import { Component } from 'dumb-components-library';
```

I think with that approach Angular should not complain about files out of the root dir.

Comment: That's exactly what's giving the `outside of the configured 'rootDir'` error.